# Transforming a normalised redux object for rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm using Redux in my React Native project and would like some advice transforming data for rendering.
I have what I believe is a normalised `userDetails` object in the form:

```
"userDetails": Object {
    "allIds": Array [
      "111",
      "222",
      "333",
    ],
    "byId": Object {
      "111": Object {
        "name": "Bob",
        "part": "1st",
        "section": "A",
      },
      "222": Object {
        "name": "Alice",
        "part": "2nd",
        "section": "B",
      },
      "333": Object {
        "name": "Fred",
        "part": "1st",
        "section": "B",
      },
    },
  },
```

I'd like to render into a React Native `SectionList` with `section` as the section header and the list sorted alphanumerically first by `section`, then by `part`. A `SectionList` seems to require the data in the form:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    section: "A",
    data: ["111"]
  },
  {
    section: "B",
    data: ["333", "222"]
  }
];
```

Can anyone give me advice on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a library called reselect, which is designed for exactly this purpose